# calendar popup entry doesn't work Vtiger

Tags: vtiger

I had installed vtiger 5.4.0 in my server windows. When I trying to open the popup calendar doing click on calendar icon, this doesn't open. What could be happening?[image]

Anybody, Could be help me please?

Using Inspect Element of Chromium I get this error when I trying to topen the calendar

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined calendar.js:1544
```

In other words the error is here

```
if (weekend.indexOf(realday.toString()) != -1) {
```